# Is the sum of markov processes a markov process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Lets say there are two Markov processes with the same state space but different probability matrices $M_1$ and $M_2$. Would their sum: $$M = 0.5\cdot M_1 + 0.5\cdot M_2$$ be a Markov process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a discrete state space, like we have here since we have a finite Markov matrix, and set of transitions that are valid in preserving total probability at 1 can be repeated and form a Markov chain. Therefore, the set of Markov processes on a finite state space is in 1-1 correspondence to matrices with entries in [0, 1] of the appropriate size whose column (or row, depending on your definition) sums are all 1. In particular, if $M_1$ and $M_2$ are two such matricies, averaging them elementwise will preserve the column (or row) sum, and the average of two probabilities is still a probability, so the resulting transition Matrix and therefore Markov process is valid.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks.